# PHP Symfony doctrine findAll() function doesn't work

Tags: mysql, database, symfony, doctrine-orm

I got following problem we building a small project to improve our PHP-skills now we are on a point where we hit a wall maybe were are just Dumb but don't know we cry a lot.

The following problem is that we have a Database with multiple Tables and these tables all got a same Attribute that is Called `editedStatusDate` so our plan was to extend the class called Status to all our Entity classes
now we try to write a `findAll` method to get all entries of a Table but this doesn't work as well here is our code

```
<?php

namespace App\Company;`

use App\Company\Entity\Company;`
use App\StatusGateway\StatusGateway;`
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;`

class CompanyRepository`
{
    private $registry;
    private $statusGateway;

    public function __construct
    (
        ManagerRegistry $registry,
        StatusGateway $statusGateway
    )
    {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->statusGateway = $statusGateway;
    }
    
    public function getById(int $companyId):? Company
    {
        return $this->statusGateway->getById($companyId, Company::class, false);
    }
    
    public function add(Company $company): Company
    {
        $company->addStatus(1);
    
        return $this->statusGateway->add($company);
    }
    
    
    /**
    * @return Company[] 
    */
    public function getAll(): array
    {
        return $this->statusGateway->getAll(Company::class, false);
    }

}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\StatusGateway;`

use App\Company\CompanyRepository;`
use App\Company\Entity\Company;`
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;`
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;`
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;`

class StatusGateway extends ServiceEntityRepository`
{
    private $registry;

    public function __construct
    (
        ManagerRegistry $registry
    )
    {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }
    
    public function getById(int $entityId, $entityClass, $entityDeleted)
    {
        $entityObject = new $entityClass;
        $entityManager = $this->registry->getManager();
    
        $entity = $entityManager->find($entityObject::class, $entityId);
        $entityObject::transformFromDatabase($entity);
    
        return $entity;
    }
    
    public function add($entityClass) 
    {
        $entityManager = $this->registry->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($entityClass);
        $entityManager->flush();
    
        return $entityClass;
    }
    
    
    public function getAll($entityClass, $entityDeleted): array
    {
        $entityObject = new $entityClass;
        $entityManager = $this->registry->getManager();
    
        return $entityManager->getRepository($entityObject::class)->findAll();
    }

}
```

this is the error what we get
detail:
`App\\Company\\CompanyRepository::\__construct(): Argument #1 ($statusGateway) must be of type App\\StatusGateway\\StatusGateway`

Answer (score -1):

You need to read the documentation:

1. You repository must extend `Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;`
   https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-the-repository
2. The constructor of you Repository must call the parent constructor:

```php
public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
{
    parent::__construct($registry, Company::class);
}
```

3. If you have done these 2 steps now you repository implement [automatically 4 usefull methods](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database):

- `find`
- `findOneBy`
- `findAll`
- `findBy`

4. All you have to do is call `$entityManager->getRepository(Company::class)->findAll()`

Some advice:
Symfony comes with a cli (if you have installed the [maker bundle](https://symfony.com/bundles/SymfonyMakerBundle/current/index.html)) which is very usefull. For example you can create an entity with the command: [`php bin/console make:entity`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#creating-an-entity-class) and this will also create the repository of you entity